# WCF and ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I got the followin error..what is the problem?

The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

1. WSModules.svc

   ```
   <%@ ServiceHost language="C#" Service="WS.Modules.ServiceContracts.WSModules"%>
   ```
2. WSModules

   ```
   namespace WS.Modules.ServiceContracts
   {
       [ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
       public class WSModules : IWSModules
       {  
           public string XmlData(string id)
           {
               return "You requested product" + id;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. IWSModules

   ```
   namespace WS.Interfaces.ServiceContracts
   {
           [ServiceContract]
           public interface IWSModules
           {
                   [OperationContract]
                   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "XmlData?id={id}")]
                   string XmlData(string id);
           }
   }
   ```
4. Web.config

   ```
   <system.serviceModel>   
   <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>       
           <!-- ### WSModules -->
           <behavior name="WSModulesBehavior">
             <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
             <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
             <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="24" maxConcurrentSessions="24" />
           </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
         <endpointBehaviors>
           <behavior name="web">
             <webHttp/>
           </behavior>
         </endpointBehaviors>      
       </behaviors>
   <services>   
         <!--  ### WSModules Service-->
         <service behaviorConfiguration="WSModulesBehavior" name="WS.Modules.ServiceContracts.WSModules">
           <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WS.Interfaces.ServiceContracts.IWSModules"/>       
                   <host>
                     <baseAddresses>
                       <add baseAddress="http://xxx.xxx.xxx/commonwebsol/wswsdl" />
                     </baseAddresses>
                   </host>
                 </service>
               </services>
               <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="True"/>
             </system.serviceModel>
   ```
5. I opend explore browser and enter
   http://xxx.xxx.xxx/commonwebsol/WSWSDL/WSModules.svc - works fine.
   I got the "svcutil.exe http://xxx.xxx.xxx/commonwebsol/WSWSDL/WSModules.svc?wsdl
   and then if I click "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/commonwebsol/WSWSDL/WSModules.svc?wsdl"  i got the xml
6. However if I enter in explore browser 
   http://xxx.xxx.xxx/commonwebsol/WSWSDL/WSModules.svc?XmlData?id=123
   I got the following error...

   ```
   <Text xml:lang="en-US">The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a         contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security         mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and         receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</Text>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Change your endpoint attributes like below

```
endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="WS.Interfaces.ServiceContracts.IWSModules"
```

This will work fine.